# aws ubuntu instance php maximum file upload not changing

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using  aws instance for my file uploading functionality ( ubuntu php 7.0)
when printing phpinfo(), it shows upload_max_filesize as 2M.

I need to upload larger images upto 10 MB.
I have changed lines in php.ini files with upload_max_filesize to 30M which is found in the folder  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini. and  /etc/php/7.0/cli/
no effect and restarted the server with ssudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

There is no effect in the phpinfo result.

I created a php.ini and put it in the  root folder with the lines

```
upload_max_filesize = 960M
post_max_size = 960M
```

and tried uploading lager files , it is not working

Then I have created .htaccess with the lines

```
  php_value memory_limit 30M
    php_value post_max_size 100M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

and tried lines in the PHP uploading script

```
 ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

The above actions  do not help me in larger files, please help. me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your web server after making changes ?
You need to Change these two things "post_max_size, upload_max_filesize" in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini then definitely it will work.

Comment: yes, I have double checked the the location and updated file content ("post_max_size, upload_max_filesize") , also restarted the server.

Comment: You sure that your apache is using same php version in which you making changes ?

Comment: phpinfo result shows. "PHP Version 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1"

Comment: additional info in phpinfo
Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php/7.0/apache2
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d